# ASP.NET Razor Site: "This type of page is not served"

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

I've created an empty ASP.NET website (*i.e.* razor web pages) but I'm unable to reach the `index.cshtml` page.

This is true whether I have 'index.cshtml' in the URL or not.

The error pages says:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *This type of page is not served.*
>
> **Description:** The type of page you have requested is not served because
>   it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be
>   incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.
>
> **Requested URL:** /index.cshtml

Here is the entire contents of the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension=".cshtml"/>
          <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true"/>
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="index.cshtml"/>
        <add value="index.cshtml"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing (or what I've added and which shouldn't be there)?

Comment: do the settings in routeconfig.cs file in app_start folder..

Comment: There isn't an app_start folder.

Comment: Make sure the app pool in IIS is set to .NET 4 Integrated Pipeline.

Comment: I'm using Cassini - I simply hit F5 and got that error.